# Proper way to stop IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm using an IntentService to upload images to a server. My problem is that I don't know how/when to stop the service. When I call stopself() in onHandleIntent(Intent ..) all Intents which are waiting in the IntentService queue are removed. But I don't want to stop the service from an activity because I want to complete upload proccess even if my application is not running.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't know how/when to stop the service.

`IntentService` automatically stops itself when `onHandleIntent()` ends, if no more commands had been sent to it while `onHandleIntent()` was running. Hence, you do not manually stop an `IntentService` yourself.

> When I call stopself() in onHandleIntent(Intent ..) all Intents which are waiting in the IntentService queue are removed.

Which is why you do not do that.

> But I don't want to stop the service from an activity because I want to complete upload proccess even if my application is not running.

Then you let the `IntentService` stop itself.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the fact that IntentService stops itself when it's done.:]

Comment: One more jagged corner in the Android SDK... sigh.

Comment: I have this problem here the supposed to be 25 seconds to 1min task don't end so my intentService don't finish - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976001/force-stop-a-stuck-intentservice-programmatically

Answer (score 5):

An `IntentService` stops itself when it has no more `Intent`s (jobs) to process.  It runs `stopSelf(startId)` for each `Intent` (job).  Have a look at the `IntentService` source or the `Extending the Service Class` from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html