# Android stop WakefulService

Tags: java, android, service

I want to stop my WakefulService when I close a special Activity AND when I close the whole app. Therefore I wrote this into onDestroy() and in the function which is called in onBackPressed()

`stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GcmIntentService.class));`

But the service is still running. Can anyone help me?

Service:

`<service android:name="com.flipflopdev.epvp_aj1987_chat.GcmIntentService" />`

Comment: "when I close the whole app" -- there is no concept in Android of closing an app. "I want to stop my WakefulService" -- if your service is indeed an `IntentService`, as its name suggests, then it will only run long enough to process `onHandleIntent()` and then will stop on its own... unless you did something to prevent that. What is your evidence that the service is still running?

Comment: `startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));` It's WakefulIntentService of Google Cloud Messaging

Comment: Let me try again: what is your evidence that the service is still running?

Comment: Ah sorry my fault, It's GCM and everytime when I send a message from my server I recieve notification through this service, so it is still running.

Comment: I will try one last time: what is your **evidence** that the service is still **running**? GCM messages are delivered to a `BroadcastReceiver`. That `BroadcastReceiver` will respond to such broadcasts until you disable that component. If you have that `BroadcastReceiver` delegate work to an `IntentService`, that `IntentService` will run until `onHandleIntent()` returns. Hence, the fact that your `IntentService` still does work in response to GCM messages does not mean that the `IntentService` is continually running.

Comment: Okay now I understood. Sorry again. So I need to stop the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to stop responding to GCM messages, you will need to disable the `BroadcastReceiver` that is set up to receive the GCM broadcast. You can disable it via `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`. Just remember that you will need to re-enable it again later to receive GCM messages again.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the task to finish, look here:

[Proper way to stop IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250745/proper-way-to-stop-intentservice)

to make task abort, set some global variable (ie. in sharedpreferences) which will indicate that task should be cancelled/aborted. Then IntentService will close on its own. Another possibility is to implement Abort as a task:

```
// Pseudocode for example cancellable WakefulIntentService 
public class MyService extends WakefulIntentService {

    AtomicBoolean isCanceled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void cancelTasks(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SynchronizationService.class);
        intent.putExtra("action", "cancel");
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public MyService () {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("action")) {
            // Set the canceling flag
            if ( intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("cancel") ) {
                isCanceled.set(true);
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

@Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        // Clean up the possible queue
        if (intent.hasExtra("action")) {
            boolean cancel = intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("cancel");
            if (cancel) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // here do some job
        while ( true ) {
          /// do some job in iterations

          // check if service was cancelled/aborted
          if ( isCanceled.get() )
             break;
        }

    }
}
```

and if you want to abort your service, you call:

```
MyService.cancelTasks(getActivity());
```

You could put all this cancelling code into base class to make it look more clean.

Comment: IMHO, `IntentService` is not designed for `while(true)` scenarios. `WakefulIntentService` is very much not designed for `while(true)` scenarios. In either case, roll your own service, one that has a threading model that fits your needs (and its own `WakeLock` as needed).

Comment: This is an example, `do some job in iterations` should call break once job is finished. Job should be short, otherwise regular service will be better.