# Clarification on inner workings of IntentService

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to understand a particular bit of logic in `IntentService`, specifically, in `ServiceHandler`:

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, `stopSelf()` is being called multiple times - once for every `startService` call. If there are multiple items to handle, will `stopSelf` not interrupt the flow of the pending items? Clearly that's not what's happening, since `IntentService` actually works, but why? Seems like `stopSelf` should be called after all the `Intent`s are handled.

Another question - when will the `HandlerThread` created in `onCreate` actually stop? Clearly it's not halted by `stopSelf`?

Comment: You don't need to call `stopSelf` for an `IntentService`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250745/proper-way-to-stop-intentservice

Comment: Indeed, because `IntentService` does the actual calling. My question is about the internal workings of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stopSelf(int startId)` method will only stop the `Service` if the most recent time it was started was with `startId`. If the `IntentService` is started again while it's still handling an `Intent`, a different `startId` is delivered to it, so calling `stopSelf()` with a previous `startId` will not stop it.

The `HandlerThread` started in `onCreate()` will die when the `Service` instance does, as its `Looper` is terminated in the `IntentService`'s `onDestroy()` method.

Answer (score 1):

[stopSelf(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf(int)) calls [stopSelfResult(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelfResult(int)) which says:

> Stop the service if the most recent time it was started was `startId`. This is the same as calling `stopService(Intent)` for this particular service but allows you to safely avoid stopping if there is a start request from a client that you haven't yet seen in `onStart(Intent, int)`.

Since `IntentService` only does work in order, it won't actually stop until the last `startId` is sent to `stopSelf`